# Getting different behavior when running bash script using SSH connection and startup-script

Tags: linux, bash, google-cloud-platform, anaconda, conda

I am trying to run a script which is running on GCP startup-script, my startup script looks like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -n 100000
source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
set -e
/root/miniconda3/bin/python3.8 /root/spider/src/rotate_ip.py & /root/miniconda3/bin/python3.8 /root/spider/src/main.py
gcloud compute instances stop scheduled-spider --zone asia-northeast1-b
```

This script behavior is not same as when I run the program connecting with SSH. It also doesn't show any log error. But when I run the program connecting SSH, it works perfectly. The way I run the program in SSH connection:

```
/root/miniconda3/bin/python3.8 /root/spider/src/rotate_ip.py & /root/miniconda3/bin/python3.8 /root/spider/src/main.py
```

My assumption is when I run the program from startup script, it's probably not getting the same environment as in SSH connection. Though I am using the following commands in the startup script to get the same environment but it's not working the same way.

```
source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
```

In ssh connection:
`which bash` command gives me `/usr/bin/bash`. I have also tried this shebang, but no result. Does anyone have any clue what else to try?

I have also tried something like below:

```
source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
set -e
conda activate base && /root/miniconda3/bin/python3.8 /root/spider/src/rotate_ip.py & /root/miniconda3/bin/python3.8 /root/spider/src/main.py
```

But no output difference.

Comment: I'd likely log the environment in both cases when the apps start.  You didn't describe the nature of the error.  What fails when you run from startup script?

Comment: There are two part of the program, one part runs successfully, but when the second part starts, it outputs nothing in log, even though I get output log when I run it using SSH connection.

Comment: Is the single `&` correct? I.e., you want to detach (not chain, `&&`)?

Comment: The single `&` sends the IP rotation program in the background.

Comment: Sorry, it was a dependency issue. In the first part of the program I was using `html.parser` and in the second part of the program (which is written by someone else) was using `lxml` for html parsing which has some external dependency. That's why the program was not working properly in the second part.

Answer (score 1):

Were I doing this, I would use `conda run` and not muck around with manual activation.

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -n 100000
set -e
conda run -n base python /root/spider/src/rotate_ip.py & 
conda run -n base python /root/spider/src/main.py
gcloud compute instances stop scheduled-spider --zone asia-northeast1-b
```

If it needs interaction, then you may need additional flags (see `conda run --help`).